# Identical folders have different sizes

Tags: files, directory

I have to separate external usb HDDs from different vendors. I use Ubuntu LTS 12.04 and according to `udisks`, both have the same block size, 512, and the same file system, NTFS.
Now I've copied a massive amount of folders from one to the other as a backup using Dolphin and I've noticed that afterwards some of the copied folders had slighty different sizes compared to the original folders, although their contents were identical (and also of the same size).

To be more precise: One folder had size `73.487.984` and the other one, the original, `73.492.080` bytes according to Dolphin. Both contained only two files (and no other hidden files - I've looked with both Dolphin and Nautilus which are the only file managers I use and the original files and folder were managed using Nautilus, although now I use Dolphin), which were identical in size in both folders: one had size `72.251.560` and one `1.236.424` bytes, which adds up to the size of the first folder, `73.487.984`.

This makes me wonder: **Why is the other folder bigger ?** How *can* it even be bigger, if it doesn't contain more files ?

**EDIT** Here is the output of `stat` on the two files from each of the folder:

```
File: b.mp4
Size: 72251560      Blocks: 141120     IO Block: 4096  regular file
Device: 811h/2065d Inode: 23398       Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: ( 1000/    user)   Gid: ( 1000/    user)
Access: 2014-11-07 19:00:54.032966000 +0300
Modify: 2014-10-15 17:18:02.000000000 +0400
Change: 2014-10-17 22:06:49.772879000 +0400
Birth: -

File: c.jpg
Size: 1236424       Blocks: 2416       IO Block: 4096  regular file
Device: 811h/2065d  Inode: 23417       Links: 1
Access:  (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: ( 1000/    user)   Gid: ( 1000/    user)
Access: 2015-02-08 17:09:14.155253000 +0300
Modify: 2014-10-17 22:11:38.000000000 +0400
Change: 2015-02-08 12:09:11.529372000 +0300
Birth: -
```

and for the second folder

```
File: b.mp4
Size: 72251560      Blocks: 141120     IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 821h/2081d  Inode: 35719     Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: ( 1000/    user)   Gid: ( 1000/    user)
Access: 2015-02-06 16:38:41.457721000 +0300
Modify: 2014-10-15 17:18:02.000000000 +0400
Change: 2015-02-06 14:59:49.784388000 +0300
Birth: -

File: c.jpg
Size: 1236424       Blocks: 2416       IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 821h/2081d  Inode: 35727       Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: ( 1000/    user)   Gid: ( 1000/    user)
Access: 2015-02-06 16:38:22.888933000 +0300
Modify: 2014-10-17 22:11:38.000000000 +0400
Change: 2015-02-08 12:08:46.368745000 +0300
Birth: -
```

Comment: Run `du` on both folders, and add the output to your question, please.

Comment: @muru the outputs from inside the two folders are `71768 .` respectively `71772 .`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may occur due of the different [cluster size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_cluster):

> On a disk that uses 512-byte sectors, a 512-byte cluster contains one sector, whereas a 4-kibibyte (KiB) cluster contains eight sectors.
>
> A cluster is the smallest logical amount of disk space that can be
>   allocated to hold a file. Storing small files on a filesystem with
>   large clusters will therefore waste disk space; such wasted disk space
>   is called slack space. For cluster sizes which are small versus the
>   average file size, the wasted space per file will be statistically
>   about half of the cluster size; for large cluster sizes, the wasted
>   space will become greater. However, a larger cluster size reduces
>   bookkeeping overhead and fragmentation, which may improve reading and
>   writing speed overall. Typical cluster sizes range from 1 sector (512
>   B) to 128 sectors (64 KiB).

Also, [this Q&A](https://superuser.com/q/420839/221259) will make you to understand better, probably.

Comment: ok, mersi, please see my edit above. (Is there a way to find out the cluster ize, if `IO Block` is not already displaying it ?)

Comment: @user10324 [This Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/q/113227/147044) will help you.